# AngularJS Material custom breakpoints

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

How to create custom breakpoints in AngularJS Material? On the [website](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdMedia), they are saying that you can set "customQuery" using $mdMedia service:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($mdMedia, $scope){
    $scope.$watch(function(){return $mdMedia('lg');}, function(big){
        $scope.bigScreen=big
    });
    $scope.screenIsSmall=$mdMedia('sm');
    $scope.customQuery=$mdMedia('(min-width: 1234px)');
    $scope.anotherCustom=$mdMedia('max-width: 300px');
});
```

How to understand this?

Answer (score 0):

@Vladimir Isayev,

Yes, We can define out custom break point using $mdMedia service provided by Angularjs Material.
For Example, Say If you want to hide/show some image at 1000px, Instead of using existing 'lg', 'sm' , 'xs'. you can create a custom like give below:

  `$scope.customFullscreen = $mdMedia('(max-width: 1234px)');`

Above code depicts, the customFullscreen will checks and returns "TRUE" if max-width is 1234px. Anything above that will return 'FALSE'. Based on these boolean values you can have your required business logic.